# How do you remove chained deferred/lazy Enumerable methods from an Enumerator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Enumerator with a CSV and row numbers:

```
require "csv"

csv = CSV.parse("a,b,c\nd,e,f\nx,x,x", headers: true)
csv_with_line_numbers = csv.to_enum.with_index

puts csv_with_line_numbers.inspect
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>:each>:with_index>
```

I would like to remove the chained `with_index` from `csv_with_line_numbers`, so I end up with:

```
puts csv_with_line_numbers.inspect
=> #<Enumerator: #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>:each>
```

I could achieve this by enumerating and putting it in a better state, e.g.

```
csv_with_line_numbers.to_a.map(&:first)
```

but in practice the CSV is huuuuuge so this might not be efficient!

To solve this I'd like to remove the lazy chained method that hasn't yet been executed, or find another solution that:

- is memory efficient (e.g. for a large CSV enumerator)
- uses idiomatic Ruby
- assumes it's not practical to build the enumerator again (e.g. I no longer have access to the source `csv` variable)

Comment: _"I would like to remove the chained with_index"_ – why? Is it inefficient or not working as expected?

Comment: A valid question! Really this was just an example – I encountered a situation where I needed to add source line numbers to a loaded CSV and this meant I needed to change other interfaces that the CSV was being passed to. It's easy to change those interfaces, but it got me wondering if there was a different solution.

Comment: @jpn Then why not only change it in the interfaces that need it? Use a mixin, or inheritance, or a dependency injection, or whatever... You don't *need* to change the behaviour in a base class, especially if it has unintended complications for other classes.

Comment: @TomLord Unfortunately I do need to change the behaviour here. The real and specific problem requires a refactor to be solved (currently data is being thrown away early on, and it's now required later down the chain). I'm going to omit the specifics here though as it's not directly related to the question (which you have answered!) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like an XY problem to me - why don't you just either:

- Keep the `index` as it is - it's not doing much harm? Or,
- Store the `enum` *without* an index, and only add it if necessary? Adding the index is much more idiomatic than adding-then-removing it.

With that said, I'm not aware of any way to "un-chain" methods from an enumerator. However, you could remove the index without converting it to an array via:

```
csv_with_line_numbers.map { |row, index| row }
```

Or:

```
csv_with_line_numbers.map { |*row_with_index| row_with_index.first }
```

On another note, you talk about "lazy evaluation" here, yet your code is **not evaluating the CSV lazily!!** `CSV.parse` will load the whole file into memory regardless, so for a "huuuuuge" [sic] file you'll have memory issues regardless.

The standard approach for this would be to use `CSV.foreach` instead of `CSV.parse`; thereby only loading one line at a time into memory. For more advanced applications (e.g. "only read lines 300,000 - 310,000"), you could look into using `File.open` and building a [**lazy** enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to skip parsing the first/last chunks of the file.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I've commented about the motivation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078792/how-do-you-remove-chained-deferred-lazy-enumerable-methods-from-an-enumerator#comment83132730_48078792. You are of course right about the memory usage for loading the whole CSV this way – the intent was to avoid making it far worse by also creating a new array!

Comment: `csv_with_line_numbers.map(&:first)`

Comment: @mudasobwa Have you actually tried that in the console? I couldn't get that to work, hence my slightly clunky syntax above. If that does work, can you show a complete code sample and state the ruby version?

Comment: `e = [[1,2],[3,4]].each.to_enum; #⇒ #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:each>:each>` ⇒ `e.map(&:first) #⇒ [1, 3]`. Versions: 2.1.8, 2.4.2, 2.5.0.

Comment: @mudasobwa That's not the same scenario though, is it? Where's the `.with_index`?

Comment: o_O indeed, I now see the issue. Looks weird.

Comment: How about `csv_with_line_numbers.map { |row| row }`?